# Sitecore 7.2:Glass.Mapper.MapperException: Failed to find context Default

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, glass-mapper

I am using Glass Mapper to bind the data from sitecore.However I get below error when I load the page.Any Idea??

[image]

Sitecore Version : Sitecore.NET 7.2 (rev. 140526)

Comment: Do you have the GlassMapperSc class which handles the initialize of the Glass Context? You need to install Glass.Mapper.Sc.Windor. Checkout: http://glass.lu/docs/tutorial/sitecore/tutorial01/tutorial01.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nuget you can add the package though there.  If you update to the latest version of glassmapper it's no longer dependent on the sc.glass.mapper.sc.windsor.  That should solve your problem :)